# Custom Post Taxonomies List

Tags: php, wordpress

CPT = Custom Post Types

I've created a CPT thats working perfectly in my wordpress.

Here's the code:

```
register_post_type( 'clases-tinka',
// CPT Options
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Academy' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Academy' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tinka-academy'),
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'academy-tax','category' ),

    )


);
```

I'm looping all those CPT in a php document you can see here http://tinka.com.co/es/tinka-academy/

Here's the code:

```
    $i = 1;
    //added before to ensure it gets opened
    echo '<div class="row-cursos">';
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'clases-tinka', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ));
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
         // post stuff...
            ?>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">

                <div class="clasesclass">
                    <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
                    <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a></div>
                    <div class="datosclase">

                        <?php 
                        $horast = get_field('horas_del_curso'); 
                        $diast = get_field('dias_split'); 
                        $personast = get_field('cantidad_de_personas');

                        ?>

                        <h4><?php if ($horast == "1") { echo "Curso de " .$horast. " Hora";} else { echo "Curso de " .$horast . " Horas";} ?></h4>
                        <h4><?php echo $diast ?></h4>
                        <h4><?php if ($personast == "1") { echo "Grupo de " . $personast ." Persona";} else { echo "Grupo de " .$personast ." Personas";} ?></h4>
                        <p>Category: <?php $terms = get_terms("academy-tax"); $count = count($terms); if ( $count > 0 ){ foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo $term->name; } } ?> 
    </p>


                    </div>
                    <div class="botonenlace">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_self" class="tcvpb-button tcvpb-button_red tcvpb-button_rounded tcvpb-button_small ripplelink ">Ver Más<i class="typicons-media-play"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <?php 
         // if multiple of 3 close div and open a new div
         if($i % 3 == 0) {echo '<div style="clear:both"></div></div><div class="row-cursos"><hr>';}

    $i++; endwhile; endif;
    //make sure open div is closed
    echo '</div>';


     ?>

    </div> <!-- Container End -->

    <div class="container">
    <?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( 'clases-tinka', 'category' );

   // Want a list of category here

     ?>
    </div>
```

I don't understand well how taxonomies works, I want a list of only the categories I've created in that CPT.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want every course category listed in the bottom of your php, right?

Well, for starters, the function [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) only retrieves the terms attached to a given post (by an id or by the post object itself).

You should rather take a look at [get_taxonomies()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies) function. With this you can query your CPT categories.

Comment: I've been searching couldn't figure out how its done any kind of help would be greatfull ty!!!